# Regex does what is expected but fails during XSLT transformation

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, regex-lookarounds

I made a regex to split a specific string during an XML transformation using XSLT 2.0 :

```
(@VAL)((.+?)(?=@VAL|$))
```

This regex is applied on some strings which have the same form as below :

```
@VAL@TEST1@1111@'Ceci est un texte'@VAL@TEST2@2222@'This is a text'@VAL@TEST3@3333@'Encore du texte'
```

It extracts everything which begins by @VAL until the next @VAL (see [there](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for explanations about the ?= construct). So for this example, the result of the regex provides these three strings :

- @VAL@TEST1@1111@'Ceci est un texte'
- @VAL@TEST2@2222@'This is a text'
- @VAL@TEST3@3333@'Encore du texte'

Unfortunately, even if it works well with [this online regex tester](http://regexpal.com/), I have this error when executing the transformation :

> XTDE1140: Error in regular expression: net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: Error at character
>     11 in regular expression "(@VAL)(.+?(?=@VAL|$))": expected ())
>   Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected

So what's the problem with this regex ? I don't understand why a closing parenthesis is expected at character 11.

Any help is welcome.

PS: I use saxon8 XSLT Processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the extra explanation. Without zero-width lookahead, I think there are two ways to tackle this:

(a) tokenize using "@VAL" as the separator and live with the fact that you will have to add "@VAL" back to the front of each token.

(b) first replace "@VAL" by say "§@VAL", and then tokenize on "§" as the separator.

Comment: I'm wondering why I didn't think about a simple solution like that. Thank you, I now use the solution (b).

Answer (score 0):

The XSD/XPath regular expression language does not allow the construct "(?=".

To be honest, without looking it up, I don't recall what it means, and therefore I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve. If you explain the problem, rather than your failed attempt at a solution, you are more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited the question in order to explain what I'm trying to achieve.